# Access docker within container on jenkins slave

Tags: docker, sockets, jenkins, jenkins-agent

my question is basically a combination of [Access Docker socket within container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22135897/access-docker-socket-within-container) and [Accessing docker host from (jenkins) docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32099532/accessing-docker-host-from-jenkins-docker-container)

### My goal

to run Jenkins fully dockerized including dynamic slaves and being able to create docker-containers within the slaves.

Except for the last part everything is already working thanks to https://github.com/maxfields2000/dockerjenkins_tutorial if the Unix-docker-sock is properly exposed to the Jenkins master.

### The problem

unlike the slaves which are provisioned dynamically, the master is started via docker-compose and thus has proper access to the UNIX socket.

For the slaves which are spawned dynamically, this approach does not work.
I tried to forward the access to docker like

```
VOLUME /var/run/docker.sock
VOLUME /var/lib/docker
```

during building the image. Unfortunately so far I get a `Permission denied (socket: /run/docker.sock)` when trying to access to `docker.sock` in the slave which was created like: https://gist.github.com/geoHeil/1752b46d6d38bdbbc460556e38263bc3
The strange thing is: the user in the slave is root.

So why do I not have access to the `docker.sock`? Or how could I burn in the `--privileged` flag so that the permission denied problem would go away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With docker 1.10 a new User namespace is introduced, thus sharing docker.sock isn't enough, as root inside the container isn't root on the host machine anymore.
I recently played with Jenkins container as well, and I wanted to build containers using the host docker engine.
The steps I did are:

Find group id for docker group:

```
$ id
..... 999(docker)
```

Run jenkins container with two volumes - one contains the docker client executable, the other shares the docker unix socket. Note how I use `--group-add` to add the container user to the docker group, to allow access:

```
docker run --name jenkins -tid -p 8080:8080 --group-add=999 -v /path-to-my-docker-client:/home/jenkins/docker -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock jenkins
```

Tested and found it indeeds work:

```
docker exec -ti jenkins bash
./docker ps
```

See more about additional groups [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#additional-groups)

Another approach would be to use `--privileged` flag instead of --group-add, yet its better to use avoid it if possible

Comment: Is it possible to bake all the options you suggested into the image? As Jenkins spawning  slaves will not result in executing the options you described.

Comment: For now, it would be OK to pass the --privileged. I finally found the option to do that.