# How to create automatic docker image after successful build of Jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins, automation, continuous-integration

I want to create a automatic docker image through Jenkins once build got success.

I tried by providing docker commands in execute shell but throwing command not found error.If this is not right way how to achieve this in Windows 10.

[image: Shell]

Error:

```
................    
................
  12 passing (81ms)

+ docker build -t snapshot .
C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\jenkins6038297422360146327.sh: line 4: docker: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Even after installing docker inside jenkins it is not picking my docker url

**Docker inside jenkins**

[image: Docker Inside Jenkins]

**Complete error of Docker URL**

[image]

**Created a new vm with TLS false:**

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --engine-opt tlsverify=false node2
```

to check TLS is made false i ran below command

```
 docker-machine env node2
```

[image]

here **DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY = "1"**,however in the documentation it is mentioned `DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY = "0"` should be zero whether my machine now TLS enabled or not how can i confirm my machine is TLS false??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `shell` you configured in your Jenkins job is executed by Jenkins executor on Jenkins machine(or Jenkins Slave machine if you're using Jenkins the Master-Slave way), so whatever command you would like to use, it must be installed correctly and in the `PATH` of the target machine, just like you execute command on terminal manually.

So the error message is self-explained now:

> C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\jenkins6038297422360146327.sh: line 4: docker: command not found

which means you have not installed docker on your Jenkins machine, you need to install and configure it firstly.

Additionally, you may want to have a look at [Docker build step plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+build+step+plugin) for Jenkins.

Comment: i have configured docker inside Jenkins using docker-plugin it requires a docker url where i have specified my url as  tcp://192.168.99.100:2376,but it is not considering my url but docker demon is running

Comment: i have added image above question, even i tried docker inside jenkins

Comment: If you're using `Docker build step plugin`, you don't run `docker `command in shell, you need to use build steps provided by this plugin I think, checkout `Add build step` to see what you can find.

Comment: yeah i understood the point which u said,on the following tutorial it is mentioned to give shell scripts...i have followed this step to config
https://www.katacoda.com/courses/jenkins/build-docker-images
but why my tcp is not connecting with jenkins docker cloud??do you have any idea why this error occurs?? @shizhz

Comment: I have updated my question with screen shot for that error i followed below troubleshooting but again its a bad luck:(
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32099532/accessing-docker-host-from-jenkins-docker-container @shizhz

Comment: Em...is the machine you run `docker-machine` the same with the on you run Jenkins? It's complaining that http header is not valid, did you tried to disable `tls` by `--tls=false`, restart your docker and try again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141556/discussion-between-rselvaganesh-and-shizhz).

Comment: i tried to create a new docker vm with tls false my command is docker-machine create -d virtualbox --engine-opt tls=false default.is this correct?how to confirm my machine is TLS false or not

Comment: above i have edited with tls image could you please see and reply @shizhz

Comment: @rselvaganesh, sorry for late response, I'm not very familiar with docker-machine, could http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30717347/docker-machine-create-node-without-tls-verification and https://coderwall.com/p/siqnjg/disable-tls-on-boot2docker be helpful to you? Besides you can try with docker http api, like `curl http://<host>:<port>/<api_version>/containers/json` to see what's the response, and also try `https`.

Answer (score 0):

install docker on jenkins. Jenkins does not know about docker.

Comment: could you brief me proper steps

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to run Docker on the same server than Jenkins I found that downloading a Docker Client was better than using the Jenkins Plugin.
You can find the latest version here: https://download.docker.com/win/static/stable/x86_64/

Then just call the docker command with --host 192.168.99.100. It should work and build the image on the Docker Server 192.168.99.100